# Alternatives to Dalton's atomic theory

Tags: history-of-chemistry

During the 19th century many scientists did not believe in Dalton's theory of atoms. What was the alternative view of matter?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4989/when-did-the-atom-theory-become-indisputable

Comment: This HSM SE post might be of interest: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/83/what-were-the-dominant-non-atomic-theories-of-matter-in-the-19th-century