# Law of multiple proportion fitting in the notion of an atom

Tags: stoichiometry, atoms, history-of-chemistry

I have been reading about atoms. Currently, I am referring to the book "*Atom : Journey across the subatomic cosmos"* by **Issac Asmov**.

I believed that if we start dividing something so we can just keep dividing it(not atomist). To prove it to myself, I assumed that if I have the power to scale my self in negative, then I would just may be become `4*(size of item)` and divide it and keep on going.
Now, I was introduced to the Law of multiple proportion and the author stated that "it **fit** the notion of atoms.". And yeah, I proved it to myself this way assuming that mass of element **A** is fixed(say x) and we take mass of element **B** as y and z in two reactions.
It is found that :
$$\frac{y}{z} \in Z$$
where Z is a set of Integers.
Suppose, n atoms of A interact with m atoms of B to form some compounds. This implies that y grams of B has $m / y$ atoms and no. of atoms in z grams of B would be : $$m \frac{z}{y}$$Since atoms are in integers, so z : y should be an integer. So, yeah it fits the notion of atoms.

Suppose, I don't know much more than this(I am in this time period when this was discovered).
Do you have any other notion of elements/matter which explains this law of multiple proportion.

Any recommendations on how to understand the developments in the atoms are welcome.

Comment: You may find useful reviewing of search results for 
[site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org OR site:hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu  law multiple proportions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alibretexts.org+OR+site%3Astackexchange.com+OR+site%3Awikipedia.org+OR+site%3Ahyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu+law+multiple+proportions)

Comment: I suppose the quantal idea of an "atom" is not necessarily implied (the fact that an atom is not divisible into something with the same properties except quantity). A continuum of matter to infinitely small size could be possible, if difficult to explain.

Comment: @BuckThorn Can you please explain? I understood that you are talking about something that an atom can be divided into something else also but that might not have the same property as that of an atom.

Comment: Well, atoms can be divided into subatomic bits…

Comment: [Issac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov), the professor of biochemistry in Boston,  the famous Sci-Fi writer and the author of The Three Laws of Robotics.  //  [Atom: Journey Across the Subatomic Cosmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(Asimov_book))

Comment: Tbh the atomic theory is quite convincing ;) I thought I was onto an alternative but I'm no longer sure it pans out. The catch is of course the required proportionality. My argument is that *solids* with known properties (eg crystalline) have to exist in given proportions, according to the law, but lacking microscopic information, that proportionality might be exhibited as, for instance, interleaved sheets of elemental substances. But as soon as you start working with gases (presumably also solutions, eg saturated), the argument falters.

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/83/what-were-the-dominant-non-atomic-theories-of-matter-in-the-19th-century

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4989/when-did-the-atom-theory-become-indisputable

Comment: BTW, not all compounds fall neatly into the law of multiple proportions. If early chemist first investigated intermetallic compounds, or compounds where one element can substitute for another (e.g., alums, double sulfates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alum), they could find confounding evidence *against* the law of definite proportions! Perhaps physics, such as the Millikan-Fletcher oil drop experiment, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment, led more directly to acceptance of atoms.

Comment: So, just law of multiple proportion is not enough to convince someone for an existence of atoms. Since, this just FITS the notion of atoms and also it doesn't fit everywhere.

Comment: It would be one brick consistent with an atomic theory and not consistent with a number of other theories. A related question is whether there are experiments that would have pointed to the atomic theory being false?

Comment: I did not think this way. Were there experiments that proved it false?

Comment: Dalton's theory postulated that the atom is indivisible, when in fact it has an internal structure. The existence of electrons, ions, nuclei, isotopes (an internal atomic structure) took another century to uncover.

Comment: Yeah, I studied these in school but I am digging into things this time. So, I would consider that when I will study this.